# variable height list view

Tags: java, android

i need to write a variable height listview. also i need it for display purpose. column numbers are constant. also i need backgrouund of some cells in different color. so, how to achive this ? should i go listview way or do some custom drawing on a scrollview ? 
some snippets would help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "variable height ListView?" Do you want individual items to vary in height or the height of the entire list? If you mean the entire list, what should determine its height?

Answer (score 1):

> inside your listview

```
...
    <ListView   
                android:id="@+id/android:list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollingCache="true"
                android:divider="#000000"
                android:dividerHeight="1px"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" 
                android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"                  android:fastScrollEnabled="true"                                                                                   
                />  
...
```

> you will inflate diferent types of
>   layouts, customizing sizes and colours.
>   supossing we have two types, rowa.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#FF0000">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_section"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imagearticle"    
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Lrightaccessory"                                     
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:textStyle="bold"      
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecciones"
        android:focusable="false"
        />                                     
</LinearLayout >
```

> and rowb.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="20px"
    android:background="#00FF00">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_section"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imagearticle"    
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Lrightaccessory"                                     
        android:capitalize="characters"
        android:textStyle="bold"      
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSecciones"
        android:focusable="false"
        />                                     
</LinearLayout >
```

And the in your getview() function you decide in
wich position inflate your different layouts.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    View result=convertView;        

if (result == null) {
    if (position == 0) { //Inflating row type A
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            result = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowa, null);
            views.set(position, result);
            }
     else if (position == 1) { //Inflating row type B                
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            result = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowb, null);                   
        }                           
    }
    return result;
}
```